# How can I install Ubuntu and Windows 10 as dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu as dual-boot with Windows 10?

How can I do this? Is it complex, or can a beginner do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is the same as it would be with dual-booting Ubuntu with any other OS.

1. Download the Ubuntu Live CD (get it here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and burn the ISO to a CD, DVD or USB disk.
2. Shutdown your computer and enter your BIOS or UEFI.
3. Change the boot order of your system so that it is USB or optical media first, HDD second, and Windows Boot Manager third.
4. Insert the installation media to your system, save your BIOS changes and reboot.
5. Boot into the Ubuntu Live CD image and follow the instructions provided by the installer.
6. When prompted, select Install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

For more information see this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot